# Limits on Integrals where one is a constant and one is a function of x

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was studying exact equations and there is one particular line I am not able to understand

[image]

I don't understand the bounds on the integral in line 9.36.

Comment: I have tried putting bounds on simple integrals such as:
y' = 2x   if it passes through (1,1)
but upon integrating (with bounds: x,1)  it yields: x^2-1, clearly not the right answer. So how do we put bounds on an integral where one bound is x or a function of x.

Answer (score 0):

First, there's a bad typo in that line.  If $x$ is the upper limit, then $dx$ can't be the measure.  So the integrand should be $P(t,y) \; dy.$

Since we can't see the previous page, we just have to guess, but presumably, a few paragraphs above, initial conditions are stated.  Something like $y(x_0)=y_0.$  That's the $x_0$ for your lower limit.  The upper limit is $x$ because we want an antiderivative of $P(x,y)$ with respect to $x$, and this gives it.  Take the derivative of the equation and it should make sense.

Comment: The initial condition is probably $P(x_0,y) = R(y)$